# Hibernate ORM in cluster environment

Tags: java, hibernate

We have a new Java project which we are planning to deploy in a cluster environment.

I just want to clarify if Hibernate is suitable for us as I am new in the technology. As far as i know, Hibernate is basically a set of Java APIs which will be working in a JVM, so the caching of objects, first/second level whatever it is, will be bind with that particular JVM. Is that right?

If yes, then in the cluster environment there will be many cluster nodes,  each with their own JVM. So it will lead to a logical mistake, right?

Comment: I don't think you should be trying to worry about the internal workings of Hibernate if you're new to it. I also hope that you have someone who does understand the internal workings, because otherwise you'll be in a world of hurt, and it won't be because of the caches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If second-level cache is not enabled, there will be no problems, because first level cache is bound to the session (persistence context).

If second-level cache is enabled, then all nodes in the cluster must be aware of each other, so that cache entries are properly invalidated across the cluster when changed. For example, see the [documentation](http://infinispan.org/docs/7.2.x/user_guide/user_guide.html#_using_infinispan_as_jpa_hibernate_second_level_cache_provider) about how to do this with Infinispan as cache provider.